# Spring Boot Thymeleaf Spring Security Method call cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

So I am using Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE, a simple web application with Thymeleaf

```
            <div class="pull-right" sec:authorize="hasAuthority('IDENTITY_PERSON','IDENTITY_ORGANISATION','IDENTITY_ORGANISATION_ADMIN')">
              <a th:href="@{/company/create}" href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Create Company</a>
            </div>
```

the above code all of a sudden is throwing an exception, did i misconfigure something? In previous versions this used to work well!

org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method hasAuthority(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be found on type org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.findAccessorForMethod(MethodReference.java:226) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:135) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:95) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:117) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:308) ~[spring-expression-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:26) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth.AuthUtils$MvcAuthUtils.authorizeUsingAccessExpressionMvc(AuthUtils.java:353) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth.AuthUtils$MvcAuthUtils.access$100(AuthUtils.java:304) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.auth.AuthUtils.authorizeUsingAccessExpression(AuthUtils.java:173) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity5.dialect.processor.AuthorizeAttrProcessor.isVisible(AuthorizeAttrProcessor.java:73) ~[thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.java:61) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1587) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:282) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.Model.process(Model.java:290) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.GatheringModelProcessable.process(GatheringModelProcessable.java:78) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleCloseElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1640) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:388) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:322) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:220) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:164) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlElement.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlElement.java:169) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:412) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleCloseElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:473) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseCloseElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:201) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:725) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141) ~[spring-session-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]

Comment: And by the way i am using the latest version   
 ```  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 ```

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out to be a simple thing: i have to use sec:authorize="hasAnyAuthority" with multiple arguments since hasAuthority only takes one argument.